# Open program files in the Firefox browser window

Tags: python, firefox, firefox-addon

I wanted to open the get-pip.py file in a new tab so that I could view it, but in Firefox, unlike Chrome, I cannot find a way to view code in a tab with an odd extension. When clicking on the code it asks if I want to download it, but I don't want to.

When I selected Firefox as the default program to open it (hoping it would just treat it like a text file or something, the same way Chrome handles odd extensions like .new) new tabs kept opening like a runaway freight train! It was difficult to get it under control and salvage my session.

Does anyone know how I may modify Firefox so that it will treat extensions like .py as a text file and open it in a new tab?

Comment: This is a good question, I'm also curious as to why Firefox does this. I find it annoying, especially when I drag and drop a file into firefox to view it, it pops open the download dialog.....

Comment: Oddly it works with other files, but for get-pip.py it did not (I'm afraid to try it again). @Noitidart Thanks, I was afraid it was just going to get downvoted, but I'm really curious as to how one may tell Firefox from that dialog to just open the program file as if it were .txt or something.

Answer (score 2):

My version of your problem was solved like so: (on Linux)

```
cp /etc/mime.types ~/.mime.types # Note the dot in front of .mime
```

Edit ~/.mime.types, and comment out or delete everything but this:

```
text/plain     asc txt text pot brf srt lua py
```

Add whatever file types you want to force as text/plain. In the above example, I added lua and py, they were not in the original /etc/mime.types.

Restart Firefox.

Note that this is for all apps that look at that/those files, not just Firefox. For example, if you run a web server, depending on the server, it may also affect that. This is why I did it in my home dir rather than /etc.

How I figured it out:

```
about:config
mime
```

This shows three settings:

```
helpers.global_mime_types_file    /etc/mime.types
helpers.private_mime_types_file    ~/.mime.types
plugin.java.mime    application/x-java-vm
```

In my case I did not have the private file, so I did the copy/edit/restart as above.

Also Note: I can't get this to work for C files.